# .bat script to compare contents of two windows folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments

I would like to write a short .bat script to compare the contents of two folders.

Folder 1: Contains some 1300 files.
Folder 2: Contains some 400 files.

I would like to have a script I can run through the windows command line that takes each file in Folder 2 checks to see if a file with the same name is in Folder 1... and if it is Outputs the name of the Folder 2 file to a .csv file (or notepad I'm easy just want a list!).

Any thoughts or help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
(for %%i in ("folder2\*") do if exist "folder1\%%~nxi" echo(%%~i)>file.csv
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much!

To trouble you further I wonder if I could refine the output?

>(.bat location)>if exist "(Folder 2)" echo(Folder 1) # Returned true!
>(location\in\folder1\file.pdf)
>(.bat location)>if exist "(Folder 2)" echo(Folder 1) # Returned false but still printed

would there be a simple way of not outputting the false returns and then on the True executions of if statement, slicing the file location so that it takes in only the file name. Possibly by popping between the first [.] from the end and the first [\] from the end

Many thanks again for your help

Comment: You can try this: `(for %%i in ("folder2\*") do if exist "folder1\%%~nxi" (ECHO(already exists: "folder1\%%~nxi") ELSE ECHO(NOT found "folder1\%%~nxi")>file.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works with remote folders and is very fast

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /p computer=Computer Name?:
set pubpath=\\%computer%\c$\docume~1\alluse~1\Desktop\
set results=excluded
set extension=txt
set xlist="ANHLIVE Desktop.lnk" "ANHLIVE EMR.lnk" "ImageNow.lnk" "IMPAX Client.lnk" "Internet Explorer.lnk" "Microsoft Excel 2010.lnk" "Microsoft Outlook 2010.lnk" "Microsoft Word 2010.lnk" "My Documents.lnk" "NextGen.RDP" "RBODowntimeLabel.doc" "desktop.ini"
set xlistcount=12

for /r %pubpath% %%g in (*) do (
    set count=0
    for %%a in (%xlist%) do (
        set /a count=count+1
        set localdir=%%a
        set localdir=!localdir:~1,-1!
        set remotedir=%%g
        set remotedir=!remotedir:%pubpath%=!
        if !localdir!==!remotedir! (
            set count=12
        ) else (
            if !count!==%xlistcount% (
                echo !remotedir! >> %results%.%extension%
            )
        )
    )
)
Echo Complete!
pause
```