# Compare two folders' contents instead of two files contents' through batch file

Tags: batch-file, backup

I'm writing backup batch file for a particular folder that is located in a shared network folder, to my personal Windows machine.

I want to keep track of changes made on this network folder, so I keep a lot of backup folders which have a datestamp+timestamp name like `20181224145231`  which is the backup folder created on the `24`th of December (`12`), `2018` at `14`h`52`min`31`sec.

All of my backup folders of datestamp+timestamp are located in a separate folder.

To do this I came up with a script that grabs date and time from the system and checks if a particular file in the original folder is different than the one located in the last backup folder using `fc` and a `for` loop to grab the last backup folder created in the past.

Things have grown and I need to compare the content of the whole folder (with subfolders) and not just a file. And that's where I've hit a wall.

I've looked into `comp` and `fc`, but can't seem to find a way. `Robocopy` syncs folders, but I want to create a new folder each time changes have occured. One thing I'm thinking about is creating a comparison file in both folders like a 7-zip file and running `fc` on both of these, but it seems rather extreme.

So summing up my question is:

How to check if the most recent backup has the same files as with the network shared folder without third party-tools through batch file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.bat script to compare contents of two windows folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149697/bat-script-to-compare-contents-of-two-windows-folders)

Comment: Your question is not so much good really; sorry. Please learn how to make a [mcve]. Also, learn [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirements, specified in comments, you can try:

```bat
@echo off

rem Set variables for size count:
set total_size_backup=0
set total_size_origin=0

rem Find the most recent BACKUP folder:
for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b /AD /OD') do set "folder_to_search=%%~fA"

rem Find the size of all files inside the backup folder:
for /R "%folder_to_search%" %%B IN (*.*) do (
    set /a "total_size_backup+=%%~zB"
)

rem Find the size of the original folder:
for /R "full_path_to_folder_with_original_files" %%C IN (*.*) do (
    set /a "total_size_origin+=%%~zC"
)

rem Compare the two sizes from these two folders. If they are NOT the same include your code there.
if %total_size_backup% EQU %total_size_origin% (
    echo Well Done! Your newest backup files and your original files are up-to-date!
    pause>nul
    exit /b 0
) else (
    echo Ooops! Your newest backup files and your original files are out-of-date! Never worry! Running backup now, please wait...
    start /min /wait your_backup_file.bat
    echo Updated files successfully!
    exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

Comment: This is exactely what I needed... Had a bit of a struggle to get the last backup folder from your code, because it kept retrieving a folder like `path_to_script_file\last_backup_folder`, so I swapped it with my working `FOR /F " tokens=*" %%i IN ('dir "%folder_to_search%" /b /ad-h /od') DO (SET "last_backup_folder=%folder_to_search%\%%i")` other than that, great... Thanks a lot for all your effort in trying to help... Cheers mate...