# Comparing the contents of two recently created folders using Windows Batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I'm writing a batch file to compare the contents of two folders on a network drive. A new folder is generated every night by a macro and I want to see what changed between today and yesterday. For example, if yesterday's folder is called "B" and today's folder is "A" and their structure looks like:

```
- Home
    - A
        - file1.txt
        - file2.txt
        - file4.txt
    - B
        - file1.txt
        - file2.txt
        - file3.txt
```

I would want to see something like

```
A: file4.txt added
A: file3.txt removed
```

But the format of the output doesn't really matter at the end of the day. I just need to see a comparison of the folder's contents.

### What I have so far

Using my limited batch knowledge, I've smashed together this currently non-working solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "\\domain\path\to\Home"
set "j=0"
set "count=2"

:: get the names of the two most recently added folders
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /AD-H /B /O-D') DO (
    set /A j=j+1
    if !j! equ 1 (
        :: send contents of newest folder to file
        dir !i! /B > newest_folder.txt
    )
    if !j! equ 2 (
        :: send contents of second-newest folder to file
        dir !i! /B > older_folder.txt
    )
    if !j! geq !count! (
        :: break after two folders
        goto :end
    )
)
:end
fc newest_folder.txt oldest_folder.txt
PAUSE
```

I saw a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150078/9391750):

```
(for %%i in ("folder2\*") do if exist "folder1\%%~nxi" echo(%%~i)>file.csv
```

But it wouldn't work in my case because the folder names change every day.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, `REM` statements rather than the broken-label remark form (`:: comment`) should be used because labels terminate blocks, confusing `cmd`.

Comment: So obvious now, but I would never have guessed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "later="
set "earlier="
pushd "\\domain\path\to\Home"
:: get the names of the two most recently added folders
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /AD-H /B /O-D') DO (
 if defined later set "earlier=%%i"&goto report
 set "later=%%i"
)
:report
if defined earlier (
 dir /b "%earlier%">older.txt
 dir /b "%later%">newer.txt
 fc older.txt newer.txt
) else echo too few directories found
pause
popd
```

would be my approach, setting `later` and `earlier` to the names of the first two directories found by the `dir` command.

---- afterthought

if the `fc` command is replaced by

```
 echo files added
 findstr /x /v /g:"older.txt" "newer.txt"
 echo files deleted
 findstr /x /v /g:"newer.txt" "older.txt"
```

then your report should be more easily interpreted.

`findstr` options `/x` does an exact match, `/v` reports NON-matches and `/g:filename` specifies a file containing strings against which to match.

Comment: Should the `findstr` addition you suggested be `findstr /x /v /g:"older.txt" "newer.txt"`? I'm getting an error that it can't read strings from the directories. Edit: Yep, that change works.

Comment: ABsolutely! Well spotted - I'll fix that...

Comment: Whoops, I just edited it too. Sorry. I didn't know when you would see my comment.

Comment: Yes - the edits were identical. What matters is that the code was corrected. Suggest we delete this exchange since it won't actually affect anything.